# Simple search for Netsuite Suitetalk API and PHP Toolkit

Tags: php, search, netsuite

I'm trying to make a simple search with Netsuite Suitetalk API and the latest PHP Toolkit version.

Here is my code:

```
$service = new NetSuiteService();
$service->setSearchPreferences(false, 20);

$typeSearchField = new SearchStringField();
$typeSearchField->operator = SearchStringFieldOperator::is;
$typeSearchField->searchValue = "SalesOrder";

$search = new TransactionSearchBasic();
$search->recordType = $typeSearchField;

$request = new SearchRequest();
$request->searchRecord = $search;

$searchResponse = $service->search($request);
```

However, this request returns all records from Netsuite, not just the SalesOrders. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Update:**
here is the working version, with the help of eliseobeltran. I had to change also $search->recordType with $search->type

```
$service = new NetSuiteService();
$service->setSearchPreferences(false, 20);

$SearchEnumMultiSelectField = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField(); //set up multiselect field to which IDs will be put
$SearchEnumMultiSelectField->searchValue = Array('_salesOrder'); //put IDs of transactions to search for as a search value
$SearchEnumMultiSelectField->operator = 'anyOf'; //set operator according to which search will be executed. Values are anyOf/noneOf

$search = new TransactionSearchBasic();
$search->type = $SearchEnumMultiSelectField;

$request = new SearchRequest();
$request->searchRecord = $search;

$searchResponse = $service->search($request);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **"_salesOrder"**.

```
$SearchEnumMultiSelectField = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField(); //set up multiselect field to which IDs will be put
$SearchEnumMultiSelectField->searchValue = Array('_salesOrder'); //put IDs of transactions to search for as a search value
$SearchEnumMultiSelectField->operator = 'anyOf'; //set operator according to which search will be executed. Values are anyOf/noneOf
```